# KnockoutJS binding change event to two or more form property

Tags: knockout.js

I am new at KnockoutJS so pardon my newbie question.

I have a custom UI control (a drop-down) that contains two value that updates two form properties. First property is "ID" and second is "Type".

```
Example of Drop-down values:
("ID", "Type") *each drop-down options has two property, ID and Type*
("A1", "Car")
("B3", "Bike")
```

In the form I have

```
<form id="abc-form" data-bind="event: { change: save }">
    <input type="hidden" name="ID" value="" data-bind="value: ID"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="Type" value="" data-bind="value: Type"/>
</form>
```

I made the control, so that if a user click on one of the options. it will update the hidden inputs, and trigger change event so KnockoutJS will call save function to send save request to the server.

I cannot save if I only got "ID" or "type" only. I need to have pair of "ID" and "Type".

My event binding works fine if I use it to detect change from a single property. But I can't have two property updated at the same time with KnockoutJS. I keep getting only "ID" property filled.

```
$("input#ID").val("A1")
$("input#Type").val("Car")
$("input#ID").trigger("change")
```

I tried many combinations but it seems KnockoutJS only change the property that I triggered with change event, in the example above it will only have the ID property filled.

Is there a way to fill two property and send the save request using KnockoutJS?

I really like KnockoutJS since it is very elegant and clean.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, Knockout has got embedded change events. Just use observables.

```
var selected = ko.observable();
```

Then on the `select`

```
<select data-bind="value: selected">
```

Then, subscribe to changes

```
var id = ko.observable();
selected.subscribe(function(newval){
    // newval is the ID
    id(newval);
});
```

From here, according to the ID which you got in the subscribe function, prefill the hidden input fields again, preferably also with observables as per example above & below

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID" data-bind="value: id" />
```

I left out `type` since I don't know where you get the data from. Anyways, get the `type` based on the `ID` in the `subscribe function`, and do the same with `type` as with `ID`

Comment: I tried subscribing to the property, but it gives me too much recursion error. I am very sorry if I didn't fully write the code, I have added some more details for you

Answer (score 1):

You can have both inputs bound to some properties in the VM. 
In the VM we can have a `selected` property that will be bound with the dropdown and a `selectedType` that is computed everytime the `selected` from the dropdown changes.

It's important to understand that the Type is not bound in the dropdown, so we should look for the type by lookig for the item with the same id in the `items` array.

View:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ID"  data-bind="value: selected"/>
<input type="hidden" name="Type" data-bind="value: selectedType"/>
<select data-bind="options: items, value: selected, optionsText: 'type', optionsValue: 'id'">
```

VM:

```
var items = ko.observableArray([{ id: 'A1' , type: 'Car'  },{ id: 'B3' , type: 'Bike'  } ]);
ver selected = ko.observable();
var selectedType = ko.observable();
selected.subscribe(function(id){
  var item = $.grep(items(), function(i){ return i.id == id; });
  selectedType(item.type);
  //Your form submission
});
```